# C# Windows Form Application: Linking method to textbox across several forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to use a method within the code of one windows form and make it output some text to a textbox on another windows form. Both forms are part of the same application obviously. I have tried using

```
form2Textbox.Text("...");
```

within my method first form's method, but permissions are a problem, even if I set them to public. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is (without seeing the exact error message your compiler gives) that the `form2Textbox` is private in the second form.  You either need to change that to public, or add an accessor method/property in the second form that exposes `form2Textbox` for the first form to use.  The first form also needs access to the instance (object) of the second form, so the accessor method/property can be called.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked like a charm! Kicking myself for not thinking of it sooner...

Answer (score 0):

Send the textBox as a parameter to every form that should access it, and save a reference to it there, or have a public static reference to it in the main form (possible only if there is only one instance of the main form in the program) by setting it to the form's text box in the ctor, after initializing call.